# how to reuse gradle cache in GitHub workflow

Tags: gradle, github-actions

I am trying to to keep the gradle cache in my GitHub workflow, but it is not working. I am new to gradle and am struggling to find out how/why I am unable to keep the gradle cache between workflow builds of my project

in my GitHub [workflow file](https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-persistence/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yaml), I have two gradle caches. One of the gradle cache and the other one is the gradle wrapper:

```yaml
      - name: Setup Gradle Dependencies Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-caches-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle', '**/*.gradle.kts') }}
      - name: Setup Gradle Wrapper Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-wrapper-${{ hashFiles('**/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}
```

Locally a `./gradlew clean` followed by a `./gradlew build` will build my project in about 33 seconds... On GitHub, it takes 3 times as long (?): https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-persistence/runs/4794532441?check_suite_focus=true

How can I set up an effective cache of dependencies and wrapper in a GitHub workflow?

Comment: The logs you linked show that cache was used. It might be the difference with performance of hardware between runner and your devbox. You can try with self-hosted runner and see how it performs. Also, I'm not sure if this cache is stored on hosted runner itself, probably on NFS and then it gets copied to workspace. See step 4 line 10: https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-persistence/runs/4794532441?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:10

Comment: I do not think the performance of the hosted runner has anything to do with it. Despite my limited experience with gradle, this project was earlier build with maven (and it spent less time than now). Locally, the build is also faster than maven... The steps of getting cache and wrapper only took 5 and 2 seconds... Earlier it gathered the maven repository (I do not see what is so different)...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of manually configure caching of gradle, use an action which is provided. From my workflow file now:

```
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: temurin
          java-version: 17
          cache: gradle
```

the `setup-java`-action will cache for gradle and maven so there is no need to manual set up caching...

Comment: Have you actually checked this? It always says `gradle cache is not found`

Comment: ???? I am using this on my own grade repos...

Comment: lokk at build file: https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-modules/blob/6fdaebfb0697acd78efa31b2eecdc26708e62667/.github/workflows/persistence-ci.yaml#L30

Answer (score 1):

you can change gradle cache location by setting cli args

here my config for ci github

- set cache

  ```
  - uses: actions/cache@v3
    with:
      path: |
        $HOME/.m2/repository
        ~/.m2/repository
        ./.gradle
        ./app/build
        ./build
        ./release
      key: gradle-${{ runner.os }}
      restore-keys: |
        gradle-${{ runner.os }}
        gradle-
  ```

call the gradle step

```
  - name: Generate Dictionary
    run: bash ./gradlew genDict --gradle-user-home .gradle
  - name: Build release APK
    run: bash ./gradlew assembleRelease --gradle-user-home .gradle
```

kill java processes before saving cache (post actions/cache)

```
  - name: kill java processes
    run: |
      wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete
      taskkill /f /im jqs.exe
      taskkill /f /im javaw.exe
      taskkill /f /im java.exe
    continue-on-error: true
```

[full CI sample](https://github.com/dimaslanjaka/android-traffic-exchange/blob/6a656e3302dac1f620043f530844220c09c9772a/.github/workflows/android.yml#L1-L140)

all downloaded jars, build caches in folder `rootProject/.gradle`

cached looks like [image: cache result]

Answer (score 0):

**For workflows triggered in `main` branch:**

try `gradle/gradle-build-action@v2` as mentioned in the gradle [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/github-actions.html#enable_caching_of_downloaded_artifacts) and github [docs](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-build-action).

```
name: Build Gradle project

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build-gradle-project:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout project sources
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
    - name: Run build with Gradle Wrapper
      run: ./gradlew build
```

**For workflows triggered in branches other than main:**

try `gradle/gradle-build-action@v2` with `cache-read-only: false`

**1: for all branches**

```
      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
         cache-read-only: false
```

**2: for specific branches**

```
      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
         cache-read-only: ${{ github.ref != 'refs/heads/main' && github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' }}
```

**Note:** this option will most likely only work for workflows triggered by `push` because `github.ref` value might be different in other cases as mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context).